# "check" If two different geometric shapes objects collide

Tags: c++, c, geometry

I'm just trying to "check" If two different geometric shapes objects collide.  One is a circle and the second one is a square. I have searched google to find a simple example and learn from it, because I don't know how to do that. I found this example, tried it, but nothing happened.  There most be a bug in the code.  Please help me to correct it in C or C++ language.

```
bool Collision(int circleX, int circleY, int radius, int squareX, int squareY, int width, int height)
{
    int distance = 0;

    if(circleX < squareX) 
        distance += pow(circleX - boxX,2); //x-axis
    else if (circleX > squareX + width)
        distance += pow(circleX - squareX - width, 2);

    if(circleY < squareY) 
        distance += pow(circleY - squareY,2); //y-axis
    else if (circleY > squareY + height) 
        distance += pow(circleY - squareY - height, 2);

    if( distance <= pow(radius, 2))
        return true; 
    else    
        return false;
}
```

Comment: what is boxX in your Collision function?

Comment: your implementation has varriables being used that are not part of your declared fuction. and stuff is poorly labeled.. where did boxX come from?

Comment: I don't know, becouse the website posted this back in 2009 and there is no explaining about boxX, i tried to change boxX to squareX, but it didnt work

Comment: ok ill write an answer telling you how to do circle circle collision sicne it loooks like thats what you are trying to do

Comment: No, i already did circle circle collision, but wanted  circle square/rectangle collision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's clear how to represent a circle and a square.

In convention, the `square` the represented as follows:

```
  squarexX, squareY + height  ------------ squareX+ width, squareY +height
  |                                               |
  |                                               |
   squareX, squareY          ------------- squareX + width, squareY
```

While `circle` is represented by coordinates of the circle `(circleX, circleY)`  and `radius` value. With this in mind, you should be able to even code your own function. NOTE that there is not width or height for a circle.

So in their code:

```
 if(circleX < squareX) distance += pow(circleX - boxX,2); //x-axis
```

should be

```
 if(circleX < squareX) distance += pow(circleX - squareX,2); //x-axis
```

The idea for deciding whether a square has overlaps/collides with a circle is as follows:

1. assume that square is located at origin of 2D plane, if it is not, we can shift the origin to center of square
2. Next, find out the distance between the circle and the closest edge intersection point
   of the square,  if this distance is larger than radius, no overlap,
   otherwise, overlap. A special case is that if circle is located inside square, then the so called intersection point is the center of the circle itself. In this case, testForCollision will return true.

complete function should look like the following:

```
//this function computes the distance between center of circle
//to closest point on one of the edges of square, that edge is on the
//same side as the circle
#include <algorithm>
bool testForCollision(int circleX, int circleY, int width, int height, int radius)
{   

    int dx = std::min(circleX, (int)(width  * 0.5));
    int dx1 = std::max(dx, (int)(-width *0.5));

    int dy = std::min(circleY, (int)(height * 0.5));
    int dy1 = std::max(dy, (int)(-height * 0.5));

    return (dx1 - circleX) * (dx1 - circleX) 
           + (dy1 - circleY) * (dy1 - circleY) <= radius * radius;
}


bool Collision(int circleX, int circleY, int radius, 
               int squareX, int squareY, int width, int height)
{

    //get center of square
    int center_of_square_x = squareX + width/2;
    int center_of_square_y = squareY + height/2;

    //if square is already at origin, test directly
    if ( center_of_square_x == 0 && center_of_square_y ==0)
    {
        return testForCollision(circleX, circleY, width, height, radius);
    }
    else
    {
        //shift center of square to origin and update coordinates of circle
        //only consider part of the situation, more to add about shifting
        circleX = circleX - center_of_square_x;
        circleY = circleY - center_of_square_y;
        return testForCollision(circleX, circleY, width, height, radius);
    }
}
```

This way, it should be able to identity whether the circle and square collide with each other.

**EDIT:** let us walk through one test case:

```
circleX = 60 circleY = 172 radius = 39
squareX = 120 squareY = 180 width = 72 height = 72
```

We have coordinates for the square as follows (including center)

```
120, 252  -------- 192, 252
 |                   |
 |--------156,216----|
 |                   |
120,180   ---------192,180
```

We can see that (60,172) locates of the left of edge (120,252)-->(120,180), distance between  (120,180) and (60,72) is larger than 39. distance between (120,252) and (60,72) is also larger than 39, no overlap. To understand it better, given center of circle (60,172) and radius 39, the range of x and y you can reach from the center of the circle is from (60-39,60 +39) = (21,99) and (172-39, 172+39) = (133,211). This should be no overlap with the square if you visualize it.

If you first transform the origin to (156,216), we have (-96,-44) for the center of the circle in new coordinates system. it is located on 3rd quadrant. if you run the testForCollision function, you will see that there is no overlap.

```
dx = min(-96,36) = -96
dx1 = max(dx, -36) = -36
dy = min(-44, 36) = -44
dy1 = max(dy,-36) = -36

distance = (-36 - (-96))^2 + (-36 - (-44))^2 = 60^2 + 8^2 > 39^2, so no overlap
```

Comment: Could you please make function based on what you said, please i would pick your anwser right away and it will help others also

Comment: I see what you mean, but i already changed boxX to squareX and it didn't work right

Comment: and beside that the pow  pow(circleX - squareX,2); have to be  pow(circleX - squareX,2.0);, but if i change it than it says:  conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz see my updated code? the code in your example is not quite right.

Comment: you right, but what is the width, height for the circle or square ?

Comment: yes, that is true. The ide wanted me to change pow 2 to 2.0 and when i did that it said: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data until i changed: distance from int to double. is that right?=?

Comment: Well in this case that function didn't work, it keep returning false even if the circle is inside the square

Comment: The "distance between centres" idea is flawed anyway, because a square isn't a circle and doesn't have a constant radius.

Comment: I just tested your updated code, it works in case the circle is under square and it touch the buttom border of the square or else it wont tell if it collide... so the other sides dont work

Comment: Just letting you know that only buttom and right side of the square works, but the left and top dont.

Comment: i'm getting:  error C2780: 'const _Ty &std::min(const _Ty &,const _Ty &,_Pr)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided , : error C2782: 'const _Ty &std::min(const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous, see declaration of 'std::min'
1>          could be 'double'
1>          or       'int',  'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &,_Pr)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided etc.. - i think min and max functions need 3 parameter, but you only used 2

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz sorry for that, the reason that errors come out is because compiler cannot deduct the type of arguments if I used int and double, I cast them to int. If your circle and square has double coordinates, just change them to double. code updated. thanks!

Comment: They have int, but now it dont work..it more worse - it give true even if the circle is not touching as long it under the square or to right side..

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz I tested one case when circle is under the square and not touching, it return false. see here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1gRs4W$2

Comment: The "distance between the circle and the closest edge of the square" idea is flawed anyway. Imagine a tiny circle in the middle of a huge square, where the centre of the tiny circle is nowhere near any edge.

Comment: i'm getting " Bad code ID! " from the url/link you give me, but i'm using vc++ the object is not touching the square maybe 100xp away and it return true still it worse than before, before it only trigger buttom and right now it triger also just same sides, but far way

Comment: @Brendan this case is also covered by the testForCollision Function. I may not have made myself clear. Try to editting

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz sorry, try this one http://liveworkspace.org/code/1gRs4W$2? I was doing more testing, so the old link does not exist.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz in case you cannot view it. I put it on google drive: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bAXChZc3yYpuq1D_it0c1L-TXHZiFirb4KkLswRR4yQ/edit  In that case, circle is under square, the algorithm works well.

Comment: just a prove that it dont work right, i can see the circle is more than inside from the left side: circleX = 60 circleY = 172 radius = 39 squareX = 120 squareY = 180 width = 72 height = 72  , but it gives me false

Comment: another test: circleX = 228 circleY = 184 radius = 39 squareX = 120 squareY = 180 width = 72 height = 72 , the circle is on right side far away from the square, but it gives true

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz for your first test case, it should return false. Here is my computation: in this case, distance between center of circle to bottom left point of square is: (120 - 60)^2 + (180-172)^2 > 39^2, there is no overlap, the code return false, which is expected. Do we have different understanding of squareX, squareY and width, height?Similar thing for your second case. it should return true

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz for square representation, I really mean the shape shown my in answer. squareX and squareY are bottom left point. so if we do not agree on this part, we will have different results. If we agree on this part, we should see exactly same result for different test cases.

Comment: I dont know what wrong, i have a picture on screen as circle, the radius of the circle is taking from  (objectWidth) / 2 = r  then x,y of the same image, now the square image we have width and height of the image and the position = x and y - i'm sure we have same understanding, but something is wrong with this code, becouse in the first code you made it worked really good, but only left and top case was missing so i most be the code and i can see the images on screen touch ech other without assuming

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz Do we really agree on meanings of terms? The new code should be correct. For circle, you only need to specify (circleX. circleY, radius), for square, specify(squareX, squareY, width, height). (squareX, squareY) is the bottom left point. If you really agree on these terms and draw those two test cases, you will see that the results are the same from the code.

Comment: We agree on the term, but i'm not getting right results. Please wait i'm going take pictures and upload so you can see what i mean.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz I walked through one test cases in the answer, please check. thanks.

Comment: Just made small prototype app that you can move the object, it print the data on screen and the return so you can see youself: http://www.filedropper.com/iphonecollision

Comment: Yes, download it, move the circle around while it display everything on screen of data and you can see that this code don't work right.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz explain to me what are those 6 red squares when circleX =0, circleY=124, radius=5, squareX=120, squareY=180, width and height =10? I updated my test case walk through, please read it carefully, make sure we really agree on those representation and terms. otherwise, it is meaningless to discuss since we may talk about totally different things

Comment: The red dot's on the screen is, becouse you are missing the images inside the folder " Assets " that is getting printed on the screen

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz your visualzation of circle and square is wrong based on my notions: when squareX = 120, squareY =180, circleX=60, circleY=124, the circle should be on bottom left part of square, while you are doing the reverse. So in your mind, squareX and squareY really means the upper left point, while I mean bottom left, that's the difference. agree?

Comment: I think so, you can see my visualzation from the app you downloaded, just make sure to unzip it so the images get printed on screen, but yes i agree on that.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz OK, adjust my code to meet your notions, which should be easy, then you will see that the algorithm actually work well.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz I will try based on my understanding of your notions. The idea is the same, so I cannot make it right, you do it on your own, OK?

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz updated, please give it a try and make sure your visualization is correct. thanks!

Comment: Still not right, i'm sure that there is something wrong with this code, becouse of 3 r. 1. my code for circle to circle work right, 2. i can see on screen where ech object is and moving, second i tried another code on net on my app and it worked right, but the code leaked right side was too far in... but you helped me alot and did all what you can and deserve the green mark :)

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz good luck. I have done my best. I can't figure out why since I run several test cases, it worked well. If possible, you may want to turn to my representation.

Comment: @ tacp your first code works right, but only misssing the other sides, please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998565/different-objects-collide

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz I saw you posted the old code in another thread. I just updated the code based on your new coordinate system. would you spend a minute to try it? Codes are under the second edit. the testForCollision function should be the same. Mind to give it a try?

Comment: tacp, i posted it, becouse your first code was perfect, but missed something. Maybe, becouse i didn't explain it right so i tried to explain things with images in  another thread, but i'm going try the code now and see

Comment: Just tested it, but it keep returning false no matter if i'm inside or outside the square

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz I tried to write down my understanding here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bAXChZc3yYpuq1D_it0c1L-TXHZiFirb4KkLswRR4yQ/edit. Please only take a look at the coordinate system. (Let me know if I got it right on coordinate system)I think I know why the algorithm does not work, this is because the shifting of origins need to consider the relative position of circle and square.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 cases:

- the shapes overlap, and therefore an edge of one shape crosses the edge of the other shape
- the circle completely inside the square (e.g. imagine huge rectangle with a tiny circle in it somewhere)
- the rectangle completely inside the circle (e.g. imagine huge circle with a tiny rectangle in it)

First determine the distance between the centre of the circle and the centre of the rectangle. Let's call this distance D.

Then find the largest circle that is small enough to fit inside the rectangle. This will have a diameter that is equal to either the rectangle's height or the rectangle's width (whichever is smaller). If the radius of the new circle plus the radius of the original circle is less than the distance D then there's definitely a collision.

Then find the smallest circle that is large enough to contain the entire rectangle. The radius of this circle can be found with Pythagoras (distance from centre of rectangle to any corner of the rectangle). If the radius of this new circle plus the radius of the original circle is greater than the distance D then there can't be any collision.

If both of these tests don't give you an answer; then neither shape is completely inside the other but it is possible for them to be overlapping or not overlapping; and therefore you have to determine if an edge of one shape crosses the edge of the other shape. To do this, extend all the rectangle's edges so that they're infinite length (use the line segment to describe a line); and try to calculate where these infinite length lines intersect with the circumference of the circle by "plugging in" either the x or the y into the formula of a circle (note: You will either find no intersection, 1 intersection or 2 intersections). If there are 2 intersections you have to test if either is one the edge.

For example, if you rectangle's top edge is at `y = 2` you'd plug `y = 2` into your formala for a circle. If you find that this line intersects at `x = 3` and at x = 6`, then test if both 3 and 6 are between the left edge of the rectangle and the right edge of the rectangle - if they are then the edge of the circle intersects with the top edge of the rectangle and you have a collision.

If you do the "edge intersection" test for all 4 edges of the rectangle without detecting a collision, then there's no collision to detect.