# Different objects collide

Tags: c++, c, geometry

I just want to check if two objects collide, in this case it's a circle and the second one is a square shape. The code i'm using works perfectly, but it only check if the **right** and **down/buttom** side of the square collide, please help me to correct it so i can be able to check all sides collision.

[image]

The problem is that i want just to check all sides of the square if it collide with the circle, but it only check two sides with the function down below:

```
 bool Collision(int circleX, int circleY, int radius, 
                   int squareX, int squareY, int width, int height)
    {

        double distance = 0;

        //get circle of square
        double center_square_x = (double)(squareX + squareX + width)/2;
        double center_square_y = (double)(squareY + squareY + height)/2;

        //check for whether circle fully located inside square
        if (circleX >= squareX && circleX <= squareX + width
            && circleY >= squareY && circleY <= squareY + height)
            return true;

        distance =  pow (circleX - center_square_x,2.0) 
                  + pow(circleY - center_square_y,2.0);

        if( distance <= pow(radius, 2.0))
           return true; 
       else    
           return false;
     }
```

**Showing pictures of what wrong:**

When the circle goes against the left and still didn't touch the square:

[image]

and now when it touch the square it return true as wanted:

[image]

When the circle goes against the right and still didn't touch the square it return false:

[image]

and now when it touch the square it return still false, which is wrong:

[image]

When the circle goes up to the buttom of the square and touch-  it return true, which is right:

[image]

But when the circle goes down to the top of the square and touch-  it return false, which is wrong:

[image]

Comment: add more description if you can..

Comment: Sure, just updated it

Comment: Your test with `distance` only tests whether or not the centre of the rectangle is in the circle. You need to test whether any part of the rectangle is in the circle. You could do this by finding the closest point in the rectangle to the centre of the circle. Since you've already tested that the centre of the circle is outside the rectangle, this closest point is going to be on one of the edges of the rectangle, so you need to find the shortest distance between a point and a line segment (well, 4 line segments).

Comment: @Steve Jessop can you please re-write the code based on what you said so i can understand it better, it will also help others too, please. I'm going pick your anwser as reward.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
bool Collision(int circleX, int circleY, int radius, 
               int squareX, int squareY, int width, int height)
{

    double distance = 0;

    //get circle of square (the center of the rectangle or square is
    // (squareX + width)/2 and (squareY+height)/2

    double center_square_x = (double)(squareX + width)/2;
    double center_square_y = (double)(squareY + height)/2;

    // check for each segment the circle position

    // check if the circle is between the bottom and upper square segments
    if (circleY >= squareY && circleY <= squareY + height) 
           // check for left segment
           if (circleX >= squareX && circleX < centerX )
           return true;
           // check for right segment
       else if (circleX <= squareX+width && circleX > centerX)
           return true;
     // check if the circle is between left and right square segments
    else if (circleX >= squareX && circleX <= squareX + width)
         // check for upper segment
         if (circleY >= squareY && circleY < centerY)
           return true;
         // check for bottom segment
        else if (circleY <= squareY + height && circleY > centerY)
           return true;
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve with the distance calculation but it won't get there.. because when you're returning true after you check the collision the function will exit from it's scope..

Comment: The code really check for the 4 sides and return true in this case, but there is a small problem. It don't know if the circle is touching the square, it just return true if the circle is in the same side, but dont care if the circle is far away from it... please help me fix it

Comment: why would you want to check if there is a collision if the circle is far away from the square?

Comment: No you are not getting my point, i'm trying just to know "if" they colide, but the code above you posted don't check that, but instead it checked if both object is on same side no matter how far...

Comment: oh I see what the problem is.. OK I wrote it late in the night.. sorry:) .. what is happen now is if the circle x position isn't in square x position but they have the same y position , it returns true right?

Comment: Yes look at this: if  circle: O  is here  and   |   | square is there it still return true as long both is on same side

Comment: only bottom and right segment works, but the upper and left only return false

Comment: did you try to debug it?! to see what is wrong? cause I can't debug it right now

Comment: Yes i'm debuging it with the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, but as i told you the  upper and left dont work, but the other sides works perfect

Comment: just to know.. did you change centerX to center_square_x and centerY to center_square_Y?

Comment: can you set the initial circle position to be at the left side of the square and then debug it? see if it's return true when they are collide.. and if not .. what are the values of circleX, squareX and center_square_x ? tell me what are the values when the circle need to collide on the left side of the circle

Comment: It didn't work, but i have update the information with more images to show you what happen and when

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz can you tell me how you're drawing the circle?
what is the circle's diameter ?